# Imágenes en emails

Tags: html5, email

Necesito crear un email que contiene imágenes, pero no se como, ya que en el sitio renderizo las imágenes desde su dirección local, ejemplo:

```
<img src="ruta/local/hasta/la/imagen.jpg">
```

Pero en el email no tengo idea como sería.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La manera más sencilla es colgar la imagen e incluir la url completa, por ejemplo `src="https://misitio.com/ruta/de/la/imagen.jpg"`

Comment: ¿desde dónde estás creando los emails?

Comment: desde mi sitio con swift mailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes tres opciones, con sus pros y sus contras:

- #### Enlazar imágenes externas:

  Tienes el inconveniente de que muchos clientes de correo bloquean por defecto las imágenes externas y el usuario sólo las verá si expresamente da permiso para cargarlas.

  ```
  <img src="https:/..." />
  ```
- #### Meter la imagen *inline* en formato Base64

  ```html
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" >
  ```

  Es engorroso si no estás generando el correo de manera automática y además cada imagen ocupa un 33% más.
  Además, algunos clientes web pueden también bloquearlas.
- #### Adjuntar la imagen y poner una enlace a ella:

  Si adjuntas un fichero llamado imagen.jpeg a tu correo, puedes mostrarla en el cuerpo del mismo así

  ```
  <img src="cid:imagen.jpeg" />
  ```

  Algunos clientes de correo también pueden poner pegas a estas imágenes

En resumen, tendrás que ver qué método te viene mejor, no hay una solución perfecta.

Aquí tienes un [enlace donde te explica todo con detalle](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/), pero está en inglés

Comment: Gracias Pablo,muy buena tu respuesta, los correos se genéran de forma automática, el trabajo que cueste no importa, pero me preocupa el tamaño del correo, a pesar de que las imagenes son miniaturas, de 15 kb me preocupa cargar demasiado el email, Teniendo en cuenta el tamaño de las imágenes y que pueden ser hasta 20. Que recomiendas??

Comment: No soy un experto, pero en ese caso (15*20=300KB) aún estás en el límite en el que puedes elegir cualquiera de las 3 opciones. Si vas a mandar muchos emails, quizá te convenga enlazarlas externamente para ahorrar tráfico a tu servidor

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Pablo.